# .NET Framework 4.7 : Get particular attribute from ReadAsStringAsync

Tags: c#, json, .net, asynchronous, attributes

I'm sure there are some posts talking about it but so far, nothing works in my case.
I get data from an api and I read it within a console application in C# for testing purpose.
My end goal is to call the data from the API and store the attributes ("analyst" for ex) somewhere where I could pick some of them and dysplay them within a winform app' (I think mostly through a Datagridview than a webbrowser but I'm not sure). I understand I need Json.net but as I use the ReadAsStringAsync() method I'm not sure about the object type I use anymore. Here is my code:

```
// Get the response from the API
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
                //Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;
                var responsedata = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                string data = responsedata.Result;
                var BS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data);
                string analyst = BS.analyst;
                Console.WriteLine(analyst);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message: {e.Message}");
            }
        }
```

I got an object "data" like this :

```
{
 "result": 
{
 "3_yr_proj_eps_cagr_prcntg": 47.0, 
 "analyst": "Jones Dow", 
 "analyst_email": "Dow.Jones@Theprovider.com", 
 "business_summary": "<p>COMPANY OVERVIEW. Dow Inc. was formed on April 1, 2019, following the spin-   off of the company from DowDupont".
}
}
```

And I just want to display "analyst" into my datagridview when I click on a button but so far my variable "analyst" is null meaning the porgramm does not see the value "Jones Dow"...

I'm kind of lost within all the information I could read about the topic, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `var value = (string)BS.result.analyst;` -- `analyst` is a child property of `result`.

Comment: Perfect @Andy ! Thanks so at the end it was indeed a json object I deserialized into a .NET object. Now I guess I simply need to send the different attributes within my datagridview ! Thank you so much